# Why does an 'After' Flow allow the triggering record to be updated?

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

Does an 'after' **Flow** not follow the same principle as an 'after insert/update' **Trigger**, i.e, is the triggering record not in '**read-only**' mode?

**Scenario:** Object A has a lookup to Object B. When Object A record Status = Paid, create Object B record. Use Object B RecordId to update Lookup on Object A record.

It seems you can achieve this via an After Flow on Object A - should the trigger Object A record not be in Read-only mode here? Any clarification would be appreciated - Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record is in read-only mode; this option causes a second save to occur. This can allow infinite recursion if you're not careful. One typical example is when you want to perform some kind of "before update" logic, presumably because you need a record Id ("before insert" records don't have an Id) or perhaps need some other data that can only be queried after the initial save, so you end up with a after insert/before update dual trigger design. I've rarely ever had a need for this, but I've used it at least once, so I know it's something that happens.

Comment: Thank you - Do you know why Salesforce doesn't throw a 'System.FinalException: Record is read-only' error here?

Comment: @gutsyfella because it is treated as a recursive DML, not a modification to Trigger.new. You're allowed to perform recursive DML on already saved records.